# Filter system array

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a filtering system, which can create the desired SQL code, when a button is clicked. Only problem is the array I used for the checkbox SQL code continues the OR statement, but I don't want the empty variables to be used in my array.

Here is the code (Some text is Dutch, but it's about skin, hair and eye colour):

```
                if(isset($_POST["Filter"]))
                {
                    $OogC = count($_POST['ogen']);
                    $HuidC = count($_POST['huidskleur']);
                    $HaarC = count($_POST['haarkleur']);
                    $StatusC = count($_POST['status']);

                    //Als checkbox is aangevinkt gaat dit verder
                    if(!empty($_POST['ogen'])) {
        //Als er meer dan 1 checkbox is ingevuld dan wordt diit stukje SQL gebruikt
     if($OogC > 1){
         $Oog = implode("' OR `Kleur_ogen`='", $_POST['ogen']);
    $OogSQL = "`Kleur_ogen`='".$Oog."'";

    }
        //En anders dit
    else{
        foreach($_POST['ogen'] as $Oog1)
        $OogSQL1 = "`Kleur_ogen`='".$Oog1."'";

    }}
                    else{
                        $OogSQL="";
                        $OogSQL1 ="";
                    }

    echo"<br>";

                    //Als checkbox is aangevinkt gaat dit verder
                    if(!empty($_POST['huidskleur'])) {
        //Als er meer dan 1 checkbox is ingevuld dan wordt diit stukje SQL gebruikt
     if($HuidC > 1){
         $Huid = implode("' OR `Huidskleur`='", $_POST['huidskleur']);
    $HuidSQL = "`Huidskleur`='".$Huid."'";

    }
        //En anders dit
    else{
        foreach($_POST['huidskleur'] as $Huid1)
        $HuidSQL1 = "`Huidskleur`='".$Huid1."'";

    }}
                    else{
                        $HuidSQL ="";
                        $HuidSQL1 ="";
                    }

    echo"<br>";

//Als checkbox is aangevinkt gaat dit verder
                    if(!empty($_POST['haarkleur'])) {
        //Als er meer dan 1 checkbox is ingevuld dan wordt diit stukje SQL gebruikt
     if($HaarC > 1){
         $Haar = implode("' OR `Kleur_haar`='", $_POST['haarkleur']);
    $HaarSQL = "`Kleur_haar`='".$Haar."'";

    }
        //En anders dit
    else{
        foreach($_POST['haarkleur'] as $Haar1)
        $HaarSQL1 = "`Haarkleur`='".$Haar1."'";

    }}
                    else{
                        $HaarSQL ="";
                        $HaarSQL1 ="";
                    }

echo"<br>";

                //Als checkbox is aangevinkt gaat dit verder
                    if(!empty($_POST['status'])) {
        //Als er meer dan 1 checkbox is ingevuld dan wordt diit stukje SQL gebruikt
     if($StatusC > 1){
         $Status = implode("' OR `Status`='", $_POST['status']);
    $StatusSQL = "`Status`='".$Status."'";

    }
        //En anders dit
    else{
        foreach($_POST['status'] as $Status1)
        $StatusSQL1 = "`Status`='".$Status1."'";

    }}
                else{
                        $StatusSQL ="";
                        $StatusSQL1 ="";
                    }

                $Array = array($OogSQL,$OogSQL1,$HuidSQL,$HuidSQL1,$HaarSQL,$HaarSQL1,$StatusSQL,$StatusSQL1);    $Array = array_diff($Array, [""]);
                $SQL = implode($Array,"OR");  $Filtered = mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT * FROM Producten WHERE '$SQL'");
            echo $SQL; //Is to check how the array is printed out
                echo mysqli_fetch_assoc($Filtered);
                }
```

Now I wonder how I can get an array to only use the variables which have a line of SQL code, but my knowledge of arrays is limited. If anything is unclear I'd like to edit it for you.

Comment: Excuse me for wasting any of your time, because I have found the solution myself. For others I will let this thread exist, to learn how this functions. `$Array = array_diff($Array, [""]);` has made the difference and now creates nice SQL statements I can use to filter my items.

Comment: Only problem is that mysqli_fecth_assoc($Filtered) is not working and I think the SQL code from $Filtered is somehow something else than when I echo it. But I have no idea how to check that. When echoed it shows what I need to use for my query.

Comment: @Jayseiwald do some good old debugging, then. `var_dump()` your query result. If it returns a `bool(false)` your query has an error. By the way, `mysqli_fetch_assoc($filtered)` is going to need 2 parameters.

Comment: I dont see any answers.

Comment: @NoobishPro Can you explain why it needs 2 parameters? I always do it this way and it works fine; only thing is that i haven't used a while here, but that isn't really important atm.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I figured it out myself. I placed `$Array = array_diff($Array, [""]);` under the Array($Array)

Comment: @Jayseiwald sorry, I was mistaken. I was confused with another mysqli function =) Anyway, debug your query yet?

Comment: @NoobishPro Yes, one column in the query wasn't the one I use in my table.  `$HaarSQL1 = "`Haarkleur`='".$Haar1."'";` where "Haarkleur" should've been "Kleur_haar" (it means haircolour in Dutch btw). but everything works fine now.

Comment: @Jayseiwald Alright. Maybe you should answer your own question then so it can be closed =) I'm dutch as well btw, so I understood the references ;)

Comment: @NoobishPro I have to wait 2 days :), but I hope everybody else sees that this is solved now...

Comment: [Please don't put "solved" in your title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, you can [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/248627).

Comment: @Chris  I have to wait 2 days before I can mark my own answer as solved, so I temporarily put it in the title. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `$Array = array_diff($Array, [""]);` under the Array($Array) it filters out nulled variables and then does not continue to generate any more AND's.

This solution has been verified